# Send header to server

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

To send the header to the server in Kathleen language with Retrofit library, I use the following form

But the header is not sent

```
@POST("testPost.php")
fun postNews(@Query("txt") txt:String) : Single<List<News>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you shared is not attaching any headers to the request. Check out the "Header Manipulation" chapter of [Retrofit's documentation page](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to learn how to add headers.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this :

```
@Headers({
   "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.full+json",
   "User-Agent: Retrofit-Sample-App"
})
@GET("users/{username}")
Call<User> getUser(@Path("username") String username);
```